# Calculate associated events

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, boolean, dataset

I have a dataset composed only of variables whose value is `1` or `0`. `1` means the presence of a certain event, while `0` means the absence of it.

```
df <- data.frame(event1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                    event2 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                    event3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I would like to have a matrix or heatmap which gives me the correlation between these events, that is, when more than one variables for the same record has the value equal to `1`.

In the sample dataset I have above I should have `event1` and `event2` associated 3 times (first record, fourth record and last record), `event2` and `event3` associated 1 time (first record) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with matrix multiplication:

```
m = as.matrix(df)
t(m) %*% m
#        event1 event2 event3
# event1      3      3      1
# event2      3      4      1
# event3      1      1      1
```

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas in case I want to consider 3 or more events instead of 2?

Comment: I don't understand--this has 3 events. It would scale up to as many events as you can hold in memory.

Comment: I mean the association of 3 or more events instead of only 2 like in the question. What about the combination of events 1-2-3 all together? (In the example it is 1 time in the first record)

Comment: Ah. I don't know a simple general answer for that. You might want to ask a new question. If you can, be specific about how you'd want the results to look--a 3 dimensional array would probably make sense, but I do find them confusing to work with.