# Calculate how many times 3 events occur simultaneously

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, boolean

I have a dataset composed only of variables whose value is `1` or `0`. `1` means the presence of a certain event, while `0` means the absence of it.

```
df <- data.frame(event1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                    event2 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                    event3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                    event4 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                    event5 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                    event6 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I would like to have a matrix which gives me the correlation between 3 events, that is, when three variables for the same record has the value equal to `1`.

In the sample dataset I have above I should have `event1`, `event2` and `event 3` associated 1 time (first record), `event2`, `event4` and `event5` associated 1 time (fourth record) and so on.

I also would like to know how to extend this solution to more than just 3 events.
I previously asked how to do this with only two events. I put the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73224299/calculate-associated-events) in case it can help find a solution.

Comment: For the first record `event6` is also `1` - how do you want this handled?

Comment: I should keep the events separated into groups of 3, so `event6` will be calculated later by associating it in turn with events `3` and `2`, `3` and `1`, `2` and `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.frame(nms = combn(names(df), 3, toString),
           count = colSums(combn(df, 3, rowSums) == 3))

                      nms count
1  event1, event2, event3     1
2  event1, event2, event4     0
3  event1, event2, event5     2
4  event1, event2, event6     1
5  event1, event3, event4     0
6  event1, event3, event5     0
7  event1, event3, event6     1
8  event1, event4, event5     0
9  event1, event4, event6     0
10 event1, event5, event6     0
11 event2, event3, event4     0
12 event2, event3, event5     0
13 event2, event3, event6     1
14 event2, event4, event5     1
15 event2, event4, event6     0
16 event2, event5, event6     0
17 event3, event4, event5     0
18 event3, event4, event6     0
19 event3, event5, event6     0
20 event4, event5, event6     0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what type of output you are looking for, but here I use `combn()` to get combinations of columns. For each combination of columns, I find out how many rows have three events:

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(combn(colnames(df),3, simplify = F), \(i) {
    data.frame(events= paste0(i,collapse=","), ct = sum(rowSums(df[,i])==3))
  })
)
```

Output:

```
                 events ct
1  event1,event2,event3  1
2  event1,event2,event4  0
3  event1,event2,event5  2
4  event1,event2,event6  1
5  event1,event3,event4  0
6  event1,event3,event5  0
7  event1,event3,event6  1
8  event1,event4,event5  0
9  event1,event4,event6  0
10 event1,event5,event6  0
11 event2,event3,event4  0
12 event2,event3,event5  0
13 event2,event3,event6  1
14 event2,event4,event5  1
15 event2,event4,event6  0
16 event2,event5,event6  0
17 event3,event4,event5  0
18 event3,event4,event6  0
19 event3,event5,event6  0
20 event4,event5,event6  0
```